# Get text from td and print it in a input

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've a table and I need to get the text of the td I've clicked and print it in a input box.
Now I've this code but it prints the last value of the table.

```
$("td").click(function(){  
    $("td").each(function(index){
        $("#prueba").val(($(this).text())); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What's the .each() for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the each, you don't need it!

```
$("td").click(function(){  
    $("#prueba").val(($(this).text()));
});
```

you can see here the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GNkxm/

Comment: thank you, it works =) I'm too bad in javascript haha

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `$("td").each(function(index){`

So, this would be enough-

```
$("td").click(function(){  

    $("#prueba").val(($(this).text())); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

with for each loop  you are `assigning the text of each Td block` to element with id `prueba`, at the end it has value of the last `cell(td)`

```
$("td").click(function(){  
    //$("td").each(function(index){ // not needed
        $("#prueba").val(($(this).text())); 
    //}); // not needed
});
```